# Can ı put together my request and response logs in one document

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, logging, kibana, serilog

[This is my logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qGvo.png)

I am using Serilog, Elasticsearch and kibana for logging. When I send a request, serilog logs 4 different documents for 1 request. I can't see my response and request logs in 1 document. When I go live with this application, there will be a lot of requests and it will be harder to control them when a bug appears. So how can I do this?

For example, my response, status code, content-type and content-language come from 1 document, but my response body is another document.

I searched on the internet and I found nothing about it. I guess I need to write a custom middleware, but I am sure there is another way to this.

Comment: What are those 4 different documents? Can you shed more light on them and why you think they should be together?

Comment: Hi and welcome, please read [Avoid code, logs or other text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)